# How to properly set binary flags in a Python polars dataframe

Tags: python, binary, python-polars

When implementing a binary flag column in Python **polars v0.15.15**, I came across some seemingly weird behavior. Given a df

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
        "col1": [0,1,2,3],
        "flag": [0,0,0,0]
    })
```

I set the flag by `or`-ing the current flag value, e.g. 2

```py
df = df.with_column(
        pl.when((pl.col("col1") < 1) | (pl.col("col1") >= 3))
        .then(pl.col("flag") | 2) # set flag b0010
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
print(df)
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ flag │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 2    │
│ 1    ┆ 0    │
│ 2    ┆ 0    │
│ 3    ┆ 2    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

So far so good, however when *adding another flag*, I get something unexpected:

```py
df = df.with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("col1") > -1)  
        .then(pl.col("flag") | 4) # also set flag b0100
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
print(df)
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ flag │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 6    │
│ 1    ┆ 6    │ # <-- ?! 0 | 4 is 4, not 6
│ 2    ┆ 6    │ # <-- ?! 0 | 4 is 4, not 6
│ 3    ┆ 6    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Why are all flags now 6? I'd expect `[6, 4, 4, 6]`

Doing it the other way around (set flag 4, then flag 2), the result is as expected:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [0,1,2,3], "flag": [0,0,0,0]})
df = df.with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col("col1") > -1)  
        .then(pl.col("flag") | 4)
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
df = df.with_column(
        pl.when((pl.col("col1") < 1) | (pl.col("col1") >= 3))
        .then(pl.col("flag") | 2)
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
print(df)
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ flag │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 6    │
│ 1    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 6    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

What's going on here, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### polars 0.17.14 update:

The issue is fixed; see also [closed issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6311) on github.

---

#### old answer:

**Work-arounds** would be for example an `apply` (rather inefficient):

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [0,1,2,3], "flag": [0,0,0,0]})

df = df.with_columns(
        pl.when((pl.col("col1") < 1) | (pl.col("col1") >= 3))
        .then(pl.col("flag").apply(lambda flag: flag | 2)) # set flag b0010
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
df = df.with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col("col1") > -1)
        .then(pl.col("flag").apply(lambda flag: flag | 4)) # set/combine with flag b0100
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
    )
print(df)
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ flag │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 6    │
│ 1    ┆ 4    │
│ 2    ┆ 4    │
│ 3    ┆ 6    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Or similarly [np.bitwise_or](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.bitwise.html) (thanks @jqurious):

```py
df.with_columns(
        pl.when(condition_for_flag)
        .then(np.bitwise_or(pl.col("flag"), flag_to_set))
        .otherwise(pl.col("flag"))
        )
```

or [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of polar's when-then-else, then cast result back to series:

```py
df.with_columns(
        pl.Series(
            np.where(condition_for_flag,
                     df["flag"].to_numpy() | flag_to_set,
                     df["flag"]
            )
        ).alias("flag")
    )
```

Both `np.bitwise_` and `np.where` seem to be more efficient than the `apply`. While `apply` most likely has linear time complexity, `np.bitwise_` and `np.where` might perform differently depending on input size. Test for your specific (typical) input size in case of doubt.

Comment: Looks like you could also use the `np.bitwise_*` functions e.g. `.then(np.bitwise_or(pl.col("flag"), 4))`

Comment: @jqurious yup that's a good idea. seems to be about x20 more efficient than the `apply`. another idea would be to use `np.where`, then cast the result back to a pl.Series, which overall seems to be equally or a tiny bit more efficient than the np.bitwise_ in pl's when-then-else.